# Batch file to use different cmd step by step

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I was creating a batch file to continuously work on few process.

1. first I have to create 3 separate folders based on input folders/subfolders
2. than use copy cmd from folder 1 to folder 2
3. than simultaneously copy cmd from folder 1 to folder 3

```
rem Define input and output base folders

set BaseInputDir=F:\Input\
set BaseOutputDir=F:\Output1\
    
rem Look for all TIF files under inoput folder (and subfolders)
for /F "tokens=*" %%F in ('dir /a /s /b /a-d "%BaseInputDir%\*.tif"') do (
```

**Can you suggest me how can i create folders (with all subfolders) 3 times in one batch file.**

1. Outputfolder  lets name as Output 1
2. Another output folder - as Output 2
3. Another output folder - as Output 3

**Than**

```
rem Log that we are copying this file

ECHO Copying files "%%~F" to "!OutPutDir!%%~nF.tif"

rem Do the copy

copy "%%~F"  "!OutPutDir!%%~nF.tif"
)
```

How can i achieve copy cmd or any other cmd from

- Input folder to Output 1
- Output 1 to Output 2
- Output 1 to Output 3

Comment: I'm not _exactly_ sure what you are trying to do, but perhaps [For - Loop through a range of numbers - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html) will help you?

Comment: What's the problem with copying all files from folder1 to folde2?

Comment: Iam not able to create " set BaseOutputDir=F:\Output1\ " three times (separate image path) from Input path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer updated!!

Please see it this is as expected:
[CopyTo3Foders.gif](https://i.imgur.com/H8D9uTd.gif)

```
@echo off
rem Define input and output base folders

set BaseInputDir=F:\Input
set BaseOutputDir=F:\Output
set Files=*.tif

IF not exist "%BaseOutputDir%" md "%BaseOutputDir%"                                        
xcopy /i /e /f /h /y "%BaseInputDir%\%Files%" "%BaseOutputDir%"1>"%Date:/=-%.log"

IF not exist "%BaseOutputDir%1" md "%BaseOutputDir%1"
xcopy /i /e /f /h /y "%BaseOutputDir%\%Files%" "%BaseOutputDir%1"1>>"%Date:/=-%.log"

IF not exist "%BaseOutputDir%2" md "%BaseOutputDir%2"
xcopy /i /f /e /h /y "%BaseOutputDir%1\%Files%" "%BaseOutputDir%2"1>>"%Date:/=-%.log"
```

Comment: your answer very near, but I have added a video link. It will give you an idea of what iam looking for.

Comment: @TravelzOnline if you need to clarify things, then you should [edit your original question](https://superuser.com/posts/1709455/edit) to add details. Also please do not link to videos hosted on cloud storage locations or Youtube as the possibility of them being removed would render your question useless. Describe your requirements clearly *on this site*.

Comment: @Travelz Online: Please see updated answer!!!

Comment: Thank you!, for unknown reason iam not getting the exact input folder with subfolder for the output1 and output2. For output folder the path is matching. I want to use 3 cmd in copy ie from input to output and next cmd from output to output 1 and output to  output2

Comment: @Travelz Online please check updated answer